# Spring cache not returning result from cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I read all the old questions on stack which are similar to this but still I am unable to get the solution.
I am trying to use @Cacheable with spring 4.x but I am not getting the result from cache:-
My code is:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class BootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class BootController {
    @Autowired
    public BootService oBootService;

    @RequestMapping("/list{listing_id}")
    public ResponseObj getprodList(@RequestParam("listing_id") Long listing_id){
        ResponseObj responseObj=new ResponseObj();
        List<BootModel> list =this.oBootService.getprodList(listing_id);
        responseObj.setObject(list);
        if(list.size()>0){
            responseObj.setMessage("success");
            responseObj.setStatus("200");
            responseObj.setStatus_code(200);
        }else{
            responseObj.setMessage("success");
            responseObj.setStatus("204");
            responseObj.setStatus_code(204);
        }
        return responseObj;
    }
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class BootService {
    @Inject
    BootRepo oBootRepo;
    @Cacheable(value="prod",key="#listing_id",condition = "#listing_id < 3")
    public List<BootModel> getprodList(Long listing_id)
    {
            List <BootModel> list = oBootRepo.getProdList(listing_id);
            return list;
    }
```

when I tried to hit url: localhost:8080/prod/test/list?listing_id=10
proper result comes but when I hit the URL again & then again query is being fired to fetch the data.
Instead of that when user hits the query the result should be displayed from the cache not from DB. Please suggest where I am wrong??

Comment: You have this condition   "#listing_id < 3", so you need to try a different id something less than 3.

Comment: yes data has listing_id in sequence from 1 to 100

Comment: But it has Cacheable(value="prod",key="#listing_id",condition = "#listing_id < 3") so, I think i will cache the value only when the id is less than 3. In your example is 10 localhost:8080/prod/test/list?listing_id=10, greather than 3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation